# How can I retrieve snapshot dependencies from Nexus using SBT?

Tags: maven-2, sbt, ivy, nexus

I have a maven2 repository from which I'm trying to fetch an snapshot artifact with an appended timestamp. I'm (unsurprisingly) able to retrieve it fine when building with maven2 but when building with [simple-build-tool (sbt)](http://code.google.com/p/simple-build-tool), much preferred by me, I can't pull it down.

I can see from [this question about snapshots in Ivy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2399099/resolving-snapshot-dependencies-with-timestamps-from-ivy) that it is possible to configure [Ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) to get snapshot artifacts but I don't know how to tell sbt to do it.

The relevant bits of my current configuration:

```
val snapshotsName = "Snapshots Repository"
val snapshotsUrl = new java.net.URL("http://host:port/path/to/root")
val snapshotsPattern = "[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]"
val snapshots = Resolver.url(snapshotsName, snapshotsUrl)(Patterns(snapshotsPattern))
Credentials(Path.userHome / ".ivy2" / ".credentials", log)
```

**Update:** After some more tinkering it looks like I can get it to point at the correct artifact url with the following pattern.

```
val snapshotsPattern = "[organisation]/[module]/[revision]-SNAPSHOT/[artifact]-[revision](-[timestamp]).[ext]"
```

With that I still need to specify the timestamp extra in the dependency

```
val dep = "group" % "artifact" % "0.0.1" extra("timestamp" -> "20101202.195418-3")
```

but it does pull the artifact. However it does *NOT* pull the artifact's dependencies. So it seems I've still got something wrong.

Comment: I tried to use an ivysettings.xml file to define the resolver but it doesn't appear to be getting read by SBT. I also tried to inline the resolver XML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, I got this sorted out but it wasn't actually an SBT problem it was 100% user error.

The Nexus I was using required authentication. I didn't have the authentication credentials set up correctly ([see my authentication question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348805/how-can-i-access-a-secured-nexus-with-sbt)) and because it wasn't properly authenticating it wasn't finding the metadata pom files and so SBT printed out the error message that it was failing I, incorrectly, assumed it *was* authenticating but not resolving. So I started messing with the patterns as evidenced in the actual question.

However, now that I have authentication setup correctly I changed back to just a regular repository declaration like so:

```
val snapshotsRepo = "Snapshots Repository" at "http://host:port/path/to/snapshots/root/"
```

and everything works. Artifacts are retrieved and dependencies resolved.