# Publishing to Apache Archiva refused by the server with Unauthorized in SBT?

Tags: scala, sbt, archiva

I have a multi-module SBT project that I am trying to publish to a remote Apache Archiva.

```
[error] (core/*:publish) java.io.IOException: Access to URL http://XX.XX.XX.XX/repository/development/com/example/core_2.10/1.0.0.SNAPSHOT.304fcd73d72ffe4a05271197902c36b9a59b4922/core_2.10-1.0.0.SNAPSHOT.304fcd73d72ffe4a05271197902c36b9a59b4922.pom was refused by the server: Unauthorized
```

For my snapshots, I'm appending the Git SHA-1 hash for the commit.

**Build.scala**

```
publishMavenStyle := true,
publishArtifact in Test := false,
pomIncludeRepository := { _ => true },
publishTo := Some("development" at "http://XX.XX.XX.X/repository/development"),
credentials += Credentials(Path.userHome / ".ivy2" / ".credentials_development"), // archiva credentials by repo
```

I took care to set the realm correctly per posts I've read. I retrieved it by doing:

```
curl -X POST http://xx.xx.xx.xx/repository/development -v > /dev/null
```

**.credentials_development**

```
realm=Repository Archiva Managed development Repository
host=XX.XX.XX.XX
user=myuser
password=mypassword
```

In SBT, I run:

```
compile
assembly
make-pom
package
publish
```

I can upload artifacts using the user via the web administration.

How should I be doing it so the publishing works? Do I perhaps need to setup credentials via `ivysettings.xml`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A comment in this question led me to the answer: [sbt: publish to corporate Nexus repository unauthorized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16425639/sbt-publish-to-corporate-nexus-repository-unauthorized#comment28924685_16593523)

***One cannot include the port (my Archiva server is running on port 8080) on the hostname in the credentials file.*** It will prevent your credentials from being used during the publish.

I also specified the realm in my publishTo and moved my credential file to ~/.sbt per barnesjd's comment (though not in plugins, just in ~./sbt).

For reference to others, here is my configuration:

**Build.scala**

```
publishTo := Some("Repository Archiva Managed development Repository" at "http://XX.XX.XX.XX:8080/respository/development/"),
credentials += Credentials(Path.userHome / ".sbt" / ".archiva_credentials")
```

**.archiva_credentials**

```
realm=Repository Archiva Managed development Repository
host=XX.XX.XX.XX
user=myuser
password=mypassword
```

Comment: Awesome! Glad you got on track.

Answer (score 2):

I publish to archiva via sbt at work without problems.  I recall having a similar frustrating problem, and it was because I had the realm wrong.  Assuming you have that correct, the only thing I see different is I specify my credentials in `~/.sbt/0.13/plugins/credentials.sbt`.  Create such a file, add the following contents:

```
credentials ++= Seq(
  Credentials("Repository Archiva Managed development Repository",
              "XX.XX.XX.XX", 
              "myuser",
              "mypassword")
)
```

Note that on the `xx.xx.xx.xx` section you only put the IP/DNS address of your server. Not the full path.

You may need to remove your current `credentials` setting to avoid conflicts.