# Why does sbt try to publish packages anonymous

Tags: sbt, publish, artifactory

We are running an artifactory server that we use for our artifacts. When I tail the access log I notice that everytime an sbt project publishes, it will first try to do this anonymous (which is disallowed in our configuration).

In the access log there will always show up two lines with denied deploys. The curious thing here is that the ip adress is also different. It turns out that the ip address that succeeds is the ip adrress of the slave (which I expect to publish) and that the other ip address is from the controller of the build server (Jenkins in our case).

I am not very familiar with sbt, but in our sbt configurations there is a part that appends the correct credentials from a file

```
credentials += Credentials("path" / "to" / ".credentials")
```

Is it possible that the `credentials` sequence contains an anonymous entry and that it will try that one first? 
And does anyone know why it tries to publish from the build server ip, where the job is not running?

BTW the publish does work, but it annoys me that it is trying to publish anonymous

[image: sbt publish result]

Comment: did you try [this?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19598435/1391901)

Comment: Hi @fundeldman, as far as I understand it, this is about pulling in artifacts. That is working fine. This is about publishing the artifacts. I will look into this definitly, because maybe it is similar for publishing.
Thanks

Comment: I have exactly same problem.