# Unauthorized sbt download dependencies

Tags: scala, sbt, jfrog-cli

Trying to download dependencies from our dependencies site (JFrog) using sbt.

However, getting unauthorized errors. My machine is using sbt 1.3.3 and scala 2.13.1

```
name := """backend"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

topLevelDirectory := Some(packageName.value)

scalaVersion := "2.12.9"

val anormVersion = "2.5.3"
val silhouetteVersion = "6.0.0-RC1"

val silencerVersion = "1.3.2"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.jayway.jsonpath" % "json-path" % "2.4.0"
)
```

I tried logging into JFrog in the browser with the same credentials and it works so not sure why sbt is having permission issues. I am using environment variables for sbt rather than a credentials file.

Comment: Have you followed that instruction https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/SBT+Repositories ?

Comment: I think you can look for answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348805/how-to-access-a-secured-nexus-with-sbt, you need create `.credentials` file or add `Credentials` to `build.sbt`